# CakePHP 2.0 pagination order clause not working with FIELD() function

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I am having a problem in cakephp code, following code is working fine.

```
 $options['conditions'] = array(
        'Tender.archidata_interest !=' => 'Not interesting',            
    );            
    $options['order'] = array(
        "FIELD(Status.flag, 'communication_pending', 'active')"
    );        
    $archidata_tender = $this->Tender->find('all', $options);
```

but cake pagination code is not working with order clause.

```
 $tender_cond[] = array('Tender.id' => $local_tenders_id);   
$this->paginate = array('page' => '1', 'limit' => $pagelimit, 'order' => array("FIELD(Status.flag, communication_pending, active)"));$this->set('tenders', $this->paginate('Tender', $tender_cond));
```

I am using FIELD(Status.flag, communication_pending, active) for getting result based on following order but its not working and also not giving any error.
required help Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'order' => "FIELD(Status.flag, communication_pending, active)" removal of array worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Is it just a matter of you forgetting the quotes in the pagination code? Try changing this:

```
'order' => array("FIELD(Status.flag, communication_pending, active)")
```

to this:

```
'order' => array("FIELD(Status.flag, 'communication_pending', 'active')")
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Bill, it works with 'order' => "FIELD(Status.flag, communication_pending, active)", by removing the array its strange but works fine in my case.